# Figure numbering with?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

how to get Figures with proper numbers using Figure `\ref{x}`?

I have tried to compile twice my `.tex` document but it does not help. 
The warning I got is the following: `\label whitout proper reference`.
I don´t know what to do anymore :/.

```
Figure \ref{Schematic_representation_of_a_spectrophotometer}`

\begin{figure}[h!]

    \centering
        \makebox[\textwidth]{
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{./Spectroscopy_and_microscopy_techniques/media/abs.png}
            \caption[Schematic representation of a spectrophotometer. ] {\textbf{Schematic representation of a spectrophotometer. }{ description.}}}
            \label{Schematic_representation_of_a_spectrophotometer}     
\end{figure}
```

Then after I compiled many times, I have Figure ??

Thanks

Comment: The `\makebox` does not look to be doing anything useful there, and will generate errors with many caption settings. But it is also stopping `\label` working unless you also move `\label` into the same box.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Note that this site doesn't work quite like a normal forum, answer posts are reserved for solutions to the problem posed in the question. Hence, the two "answers" you posted below will soon be deleted. The one about the warnings would have been better suited as an edit to your question, and the other one should rather have been a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Carlisle pointed out the problem seems to be in the `\makebox`. Try to remove it. As a remark I also changed the positioneing argument to `[htb]`, especially for large picture the `[h!]` can be problematic for TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Figure \ref{Schematic_representation_of_a_spectrophotometer}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
  \caption[Schematic representation of a spectrophotometer. ] {\textbf{Schematic representation of a spectrophotometer. }{ description.}}
  \label{Schematic_representation_of_a_spectrophotometer}     
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the aim is to have the picture the same width as the text, the `figure` environment can be written

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption[Schematic representation of a spectrophotometer. ] {\textbf{Schematic representation of a spectrophotometer. }{ description.}}
  \label{Schematic_representation_of_a_spectrophotometer}     
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the OP's objective appears to be to make the graph as wide as the text block, I would also replace `[scale=0.5]` with `[width=\textwidth]`. Doing so would also permit getting rid of the superfluous `\centering` directive.

Comment: @Mico You are probably right, I added it. It is not entirely clear from the question since the `\makebox` is `\textwidth` but the picture has `scale=1`.